# Handling IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, filter-driver

I am working on an upper volume filter driver using diskperf as base.
I am handling `IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN` IRP, so while shutting down the system I want to save a buffer of size ranging from 30Mb to 500Mb.
So can I write this buffer to a file and when the system reboots again our driver should read the buffer from that file, so is this possible?
If yes, then can anyone guide me which functions to use for it?

Awaiting a positive response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using the ordinary kernel-mode file management functions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell which functions you are referring to? I tried to use `IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest(IRP_MJ_WRITE....)` but it did not worked. Can I use the `IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest` in an upper volume filter driver?

Comment: Much easier to use `ZwCreateFile` and friends, though you would need to launch a separate system thread to perform the operation.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I have used `ZwCreateFile` and `ZwWriteFile` but I am continuously getting `0xC0000022->STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` status after `ZwWriteFile` function. Can you please tell what can be the possible solution?

`status = ZwCreateFile(&devhandle,FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA,&obj_attrib,&file_status,NULL,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,FILE_OPEN,FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE,NULL,0);

 lDiskOffset.QuadPart = (43680 * sectorsize); 
 status = ZwWriteFile(devhandle,NULL,NULL,NULL,&ioStatus,wrtBuffer,sizeof(wrtBuffer),&lDiskOffset,NULL);
 } 
 ZwClose(devhandle);
}`

Comment: Just a guess, but try `GENERIC_ALL` permission instead of `FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA`.  Also, try the same code from a different context (e.g., via IOCTL) in case the problem is that the file system you're trying to write to has already shut down.

Comment: Hi, @HarryJohnston I followed your suggestion and used `GENERIC_ALL` permission instead of `FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA` but still got the same status code `0xC0000022->STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`. Which IOCTL you are talking of? I tried to use `IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest` with `IRP_MJ_WRITE` but it too didn't yield the desired result.

Comment: I meant that your driver could implement an IOCTL (which you can call from user mode) that tries using `ZwCreateFile` and `ZwWriteFile`.  Once you've got them working in that context, then try it from IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston for your replies, now my problem is solved, I was making a mistake. I was specifying the filename as `L"\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1"` instead of `L"\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1\\filename.txt"`, so now the problem is solved. I have one more issue, I want to now read this file during boot, before any writes occurs to any partition. I tried to use `ZwOpenFile & ZwReadFile` but was not successful, got this error code `0xC0000008->STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`, though it works properly once the partition is mounted. How can I know when the partition is actually mounted?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, the error code I am getting after `ZwOpenFile` is, `C000000E->STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE`, the above error code is for `ZwReadFile`.

Comment: No idea.  I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel provides a set of support routines to kernel-mode drivers, including [`ZwCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and various related functions) for working with files.  So there is no need to attempt to construct requests to the file system drivers yourself.